# Web video (YouTube, etc) doesn't play in Chrome after suspend

Tags: nvidia, video, google-chrome, suspend

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10 and nvidia-346 driver After a suspend, all websites doesn't play video in Chrome.  Firefox appears to still play video.

The video still loads. If I "click forward in time" you can see that frame from the video.  It just won't play.

I experienced the same behavior with the `nvidia nouveau driver and nvidia-331`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you install Ubuntu some packages are not installed out of legal issues. This might fix

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
```

And run ,

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```